# Cannot use expectation in Chai.js with Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, chai, nightwatch.js

I build simple e2e test with Nightwatch. This simple e2e test is passed successfully.
Next, I build second test to use Chai.js / Mocha.js. But this test raises exception.

```
// First(successfully passed)
module.exports = {
  'increment counter': browser => {
    browser
      .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
      .click("button#plus-btn")
      .assert.containsText('h1', '1')
      .end()
  },
  "decrement counter": browser => {
    browser
      .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
      .click("button#minus-btn")
      .assert.containsText('h1', '-1')
      .end()
  }
}
```

```
// Second
describe('counter testing', () => {

  describe('press plus button', () => {

    it('increments counter', (browser) => {
      browser
        .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
        .click("button#plus-btn")
        .expect.element('h1').text.to.equal('1')
        .end()
    })
  })

  describe('press minus button', () => {

    it('decrements counter', (browser) => {
      browser
        .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
        .click("button#minus-btn")
        .expect.element('h1').text.to.equal('-1')
        .end()
    })
  })
})
```

Exception message

```
TypeError: browser.url(...).click(...).expect.element(...).text.to.equal(...).end is not a function
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide), you should call `end` in a different way when using `expect` for assertions. I think it's because the `expect` way is based on `chai`. Changing your tests to look like this will work

```
it("increments counter", browser => {
  browser
    .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    .click("button#plus-btn")
    .expect.element("h1")
    .text.to.equal("1");
  // See how end is called differently
  browser.end();
});
```